# Get all custom attributes added for products - programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I have added few attributes in Magento like Veg, NonVeg etc.
Is there any way to get all newly added attributes from Magento? I do not want those attributes which were already present.

Comment: I found the answer here, answered by Marius:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251243/distinguish-between-magento-product-attributes-and-custom-created-product-attrib

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the attributes created by users:

`Go to -> Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`. And filter by `System = No`

All attributes filtered `less  -> color, cost and manufacturer` are the attributes created by users

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want it programmatically.